# Best way to replace two first characters of String from every line JAVA

Tags: java, substring

I have a text file with about 3 million lines and I need to replace the first two characters of every line with "". 
My current code is

```
String[] lines = content.split("\n");
        content = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<lines.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            lines[i].substring(2);
            content = content + lines[i];
        }
```

It takes it about 3-4 days to finish.
Is there a faster way of doing this?

My entire code:

```
 try {
        String content = readFile("text.txt", StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        content = content.replaceAll("\\d","");
        content = content.replaceAll("\\.","");
        String[] lines = content.split("\n");
        content = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<lines.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            lines[i].substring(2);
            content = content + lines[i];
        }
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("texty text.txt");
        out.println(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Rosenpin: 3 million lines is *trivial* to process. You just need to avoid one of the most famous performance killers in all of Java - repeated string concatenation.

Comment: @Rosenpin what? Unix/Linux command line utilities make that a breeze...

Comment: Reading the whole file in memoty is also a bad idea. Read the file line by line, process each line, and write it to the other file. Make sure to use a buffered reader and a buffered writer.

Comment: `cut -c3- text.txt > "texty text.txt"` on a Linux box does that in about a second

Comment: Do You really need to do it in Java ? There are way better tools to do it (at least in Lunux), like sed: `sed 's/^..//' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: Read a line at a time, and for &diety's sake, *don't* do this: `content = content + lines[i];` -- that is a horrible performance killer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a faster way of doing this?

Yes - don't perform repeated string concatenation. *That's* the part that's killing your performance. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

It's also not even doing what you want it to - you're not using the result of calling `substring`.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
String[] lines = content.split("\n");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines) {
    builder.append(line.substring(2));
    // I suspect you want this, otherwise you're losing line breaks.
    builder.append("\n");
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Additionally, you should consider *reading* the file line by line instead of reading the whole thing and then splitting it. For example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader reader = ...) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line.substring(2));
        builder.append("\n");
    }
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

And unless you really need the whole thing in memory at any one time at all, *write* the lines as you process them:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = ...,
     BufferedWriter writer = ...) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Perform any other manipulations here...
        writer.write(line.substring(2));
        writer.write("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why read the whole thing into memory? Why build the whole result in memory? Just write each line out?

Comment: @djna: See my edit - and I'll add more now that we know what the OP is doing.

Comment: Works! 
Thank you.
Will mark as answered in 10 minutes(stupid stack overflow rule)

Comment: @Rosenpin: Make sure you read the updated answer. Basically, unless you *need* to have the whole thing in memory for some reason, process it all line by line instead.

Comment: Oh by the way my file weights "only" 68 MB now, is there a way to reduce it's size?

Comment: @Rosenpin: That sounds like an entirely different question, which should be asked in a separate post with a *lot* more information. Without knowing anything about what's in your file or what uses it, how can we say how it could be reduced in size? Could you just zip it, for example? Does it contain a load of redundant information?

Comment: I'll add a separate question for that.

Comment: I was just curious about how fast this would be: Using the last version (no need to hold everything in memory), copying a file with 3 mio lines, 80 chars each, was done in less than 2 seconds!

Answer (score 5):

Why, oh why do you read the whole shebang at once in memory? Just read a line from a buffered file reader, write a line to a buffered file writer.

Comment: I actually did that at first but then I thought that what's causing it to go slow.

Comment: Then you first measure, then you optimize. Did you time exactly which parts of your code are slow? 3-4 days is a ridiculous amount of time for something trivial.

Comment: It was slow because I recreated the final String in the while loop

Answer (score 4):

`sed` will be much faster in this case:

```
sed 's/^..//' file > output
```

The reason why your code is so slow is that you concatenate strings with `+`. That creates a new object, copies the content of the two old strings and then forgets about the two old strings. That puts a lot of stress on the VM.

Try it with `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you run the GC one million times, then you'll see a similar effect.

Comment: Sure, if he generated garbage - but he's just creating large character arrays, and (I think) GC time is relative to the number of objects, not their size (but then again I haven't had the need to read up on this recently...)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos at each iteration, he replaces the current result with a new one, efectively creating 3 million useless strings, which are larger and larger at each iteration.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos: GC is relative to the number or *retained* objects. So when you have 100000 reachable objects and two of them become unreachable per loop iteration, then you still have to check links to 100000 objects on each GC run. He would be fine if the number of objects would drop drastically per GC run.

Answer (score 2):

First of all.
Almost every line of your code is super uneffective.

1. Delete `System.out.println(i);` it is very heavy to machine
2. `substring(2);` it is also very heavy, try to change it for example to `lines[i].chatAt(...)`
3. I gues that content is String, and look what are you doing. every loop iteration you are creating new Sting `content=""`. Make some StringBuilder, and use append.
4. If you can change it to BufferReader, or FileReader